# How to find the points of intersection between a line and ellipse in R

Tags: r, line, intersection, ellipse

I would like to find the points of intersection between an ellipse and a line

If using the example (ignoring a few un-needed arguments) from the dataEllipse function from the car package i.e.

```
x <- dataEllipse(Prestige$income, Prestige$education, levels=0.95, lty=2)
```

and say you have the horizontal line

```
abline(14,0)
```

how do you find the two points of intersection between the line and the ellipse

I know you can get the data that makes the ellipse from just looking at x, however I would like to get the exact points of intersection.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of an ellipse is given by:

x^2/a+y^2/b=1, and the equation of a line by cx+d=y (where a,b,c,d coefficients).

You can substitute y in the ellipse equation. Then the goal is to find the solution of f(x)=0.  You can use some method like bisection to solve such a problem.

Check this out:

http://www.math.wichita.edu/~cma/stat774/ch2.pdf

Comment: I am aware of the equation of an ellipse, however I do not have the coefficients for this particular ellipse that has been generated from the data, unless I am missing something...

Comment: I do however have x and y coordinates of the ellipse, can I get the coefficients from that data?

Answer (score 0):

I bet there's a curve-fitting method that can get the foci and axis lengths of your ellipse from the set of x-y coords, but it looks tough: http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~mstoj075/Publications_files/EllipseFit.pdf .  You might get a "good enough" answer by using `splinefun` on your set of x-y coordinate data  and following the answers in [The intersection point between a spline and a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234261/the-intersection-point-between-a-spline-and-a-line)